# Intermittent video hang-up when recording rtsp stream using

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, rtsp

I write a rtsp stream with ffmpeg to raspberry pi. When recording for a long time, it starts to hang from one second to 20 seconds. I used ffmpeg version 4.2.2 for the recording. I noticed this problem on raspberry pi models 2, 3 and 4 but when writing to my computer this problem was not noticed. The command to write ffmpeg:

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 3000000 -i rtsp://192.168.1.10:554/user=admin\&password=\&channel=1\&stream=0.sdp? -hide_banner  -y -vcodec copy -f segment -segment_time 300 -segment_start_number 1 -segment_format mp4 -reset_timestamps 1 -flush_packets 1 /media/CD/TV_%d.mp4 -fflags +genpts -vsync 0 -enc_time_base -1`

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: If the command works locally but not over a network there is a good chance the network is the issue.  You should check if you have sufficient bandwidth to carry your stream. Try lowering your bitrate and see if the issue depends on it. If your application prefers losing a few frames and catching up to freezing and trying to recover the lost data, try using UDP instead of TCP it won't resend data if lost (not UDP itself) but it won't fix the bandwidth problem if you have one.